# Linebreak (in code) causes unwanted margin in HTML output

Tags: html, css

I have a menu, separated by DIV-s.
When this look like that:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>
</div>
```

it renderers well, but thats not nice. But if I do that:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
```

an unwanted space gets in the output. There is a gap between DIV's.
How to fix this?

EDIT:
sorry for everyone. Here is a detailed fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/qK5Bq/

```
.places_histNavigator {
    color: #AC3B75;
    font-family: georgiab;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 38px;
}

.places_histNavigatorElement {
    border-left: 1px solid #F3F2EB;
    border-right: 1px solid #C2BEA8;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

<div class="places_histNavigator">
<div style="width: 20%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">1<span class="customSelect legordulo" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="customSelectInner" style="width: 34px; display: inline-block;">25</span></span></div>
<div style="width: 19%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">2</div>
<div style="width: 20%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">3</div>
<div style="width: 15%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">4</div>
<div style="width: 23%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">5</div>
</div>

<div class="places_histNavigator">
<div style="width: 20%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">1<span class="customSelect legordulo" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="customSelectInner" style="width: 34px; display: inline-block;">25</span></span></div>
  <hr>
<div style="width: 19%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">2</div><div style="width: 20%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">3</div><div style="width: 15%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">4</div><div style="width: 23%;" class="places_histNavigatorElement">5</div></div>
```

Comment: i am assuming `container` is `inline` but still can you show your css please....

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are saying: http://jsfiddle.net/45Rdy/

Comment: well Im sorry, I didnt thought CSS was necessary... a sec

Comment: Here's a link explaining the issue and some ways to approach it: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the assumtion posted in the comment, here is a possible solution :  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/45Rdy/2/)

`Inline` attributes consider the spaces existing in between the `div`s, to avoid it, either use `block` display or added `<!--->`(html comment mark) in between the divs.

**CSS**

```
 *{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#container1,#container2 {
    display:block /* this is the key, make sure it's not marked inline */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container1">
    <div>1</div><div>2</div><div>3</div>
</div>
<br />
<div id="container2">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

i really dont get what you are trying to achieve, but if you want things to display in one line, check this [**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/qK5Bq/3/), consider adding `white-space:nowrap;` to your code if you want to kill extra white spaces in one line.

**CSS** (2 lines changed)

```
.places_histNavigator {
    color: #AC3B75;
    font-family: georgiab;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    line-height: 38px;
    white-space:nowrap; /* added this */
    display:block ; /* optional for uniformity*/
}
```

**2nd EDIT**

See, as posted in comment, `inline` attributes consider even the spaces in between the div's...i.e....if you have a markup like this `<div> </div>` with nothing in between, and its `inline`, then space between them WOULD BE PARSED by browser and rendered on webpage, to avoid that, (like i said before) place `<!-->` or change `display` type.
 [**Final Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/qK5Bq/5/)

Comment: I checked the edited version, still wrong. Just check both up and down lines, there are still that unwanted gaps (between the gray-lightgray lines, about 5 pixels)

Comment: the problem is, there is an ENTER or SPACE characters in HTML source, which cannot be hidden by CSS I guess

Comment: m bad with Morse codes....u freaking out because its again not working or something??????

Comment: dont worry, it does work :) I just throw my hat to the floor seeing the <!-- ->>

Answer (score 1):

add `margin:0px;` and `padding:0px;` to your body HTML

Answer (score 1):

If your `div` elements are set to display `inline` they are effectively being handled like words, so the HTML formatting is important- in this case new lines create spaces. If you wish to format your HTML but control out this effect, you can set the elements to `inline-block` then manually control their margins to counter-act this effect, or possibly set `word-spacing` on the parent.